# Evaluate $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{|t|^{g(x)}}dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ Lipschitz and bounded.

How can I calculate

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{|t|^{g(x)}}dt$$

Where $g:\mathbb{R} \to (1,2)$?

Comment: but what is $f_n$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton You're right.

Comment: @Vim A typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are there no differentiability restrictions on $g(x)$?